# BFS algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search

I am working on a project that requires me to implement the BFS algorithm using Python, which I am new to.

The algorithm finishes execution of a 9 pieces puzzle (3x3), but it takes a really large amount of time to do so (5 minutes):

```
def bfs(self):

    fringe = deque([])
    # start it
    fringe.append(self.stateObj.getState())

    while len(fringe) > 0:
        state = fringe.popleft()
        self.visited.append(state)

        # just for tracing
        # self.helper.drawBoard(state)

        if self.stateObj.isCurrentStateGoalTest(state):
            return True

        for next_state in self.stateObj.getNextStates(state):
            if (next_state not in (self.visited + list(fringe))):
                fringe.append(next_state)
```

Can anybody point out what I could improve this to achieve better performance?
Any practical answer is well accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problematic part is probably this: `if (next_state not in (self.visited + list(fringe)))` This will a) create a new list from `fringe`, b) create *another* new list from that list and `visited`, c) iterate the entire list to see whether the next state is already in.

It seems like `self.visited` is a `list`. Make it a `set` instead, so the `in` check takes only O(1) instead of O(n). Also, in BFS you can add the elements to `visited` right in the `next_state` loop, so you don't have to check whether they are in the `fringe`, as well.

```
def bfs(self):
    fringe = deque([self.stateObj.getState()])
    while fringe:
        state = fringe.popleft()
        if self.stateObj.isCurrentStateGoalTest(state):
            return True
        for next_state in self.stateObj.getNextStates(state):
            if next_state not in self.visited:
                fringe.append(next_state)
                self.visited.add(next_state)
```

If that's not enough, I suggest using [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) instead, using the number of misplaced tiles as a heuristic function.

Answer (score -1):

very basic code ig

```
import queue

adj = { 0:[1,3,4], 1:[0,2,4], 2:[1,6], 3:[0,4,6], 4:[0,1,3,5], 5:[4], 6:[2,3] }


def bfs(vertex, adj):
  vis = []
  q = queue.Queue()
  popped_res = []
  q.put(vertex)
  vis.append(vertex)

  while q.qsize() != 0:
    top = q.get()
    popped_res.append(top)
    for child in adj[top]:
      if child in vis:
        continue
      vis.append(child)
      q.put(child)


  return popped_res

print(bfs(0, adj))
```